# Where can i find/generate the wav file from torch

Tags: python, pytorch

This code below generates an Audio output using IPython. I could only play this in a notebook(colab) and i want to export the wav file.

````
    if len(i) < 1: continue;
    print(i)
    if raw_input:
        if i[-1] != ";": i=i+";" 
    else: i = ARPA(i)
    print(i)
    with torch.no_grad(): # save VRAM by not including gradients
        sequence = np.array(text_to_sequence(i, ['english_cleaners']))[None, :]
        sequence = torch.autograd.Variable(torch.from_numpy(sequence)).cuda().long()
        mel_outputs, mel_outputs_postnet, _, alignments = model.inference(sequence)
        audio = waveglow.infer(mel_outputs_postnet, sigma=sigma); print(""); ipd.display(ipd.Audio(audio[0].data.cpu().numpy(), rate=hparams.sampling_rate))```
````

Comment: So, what is `audio`?  Is it just an array of audio samples?  Python has a `wave` module that can create a .wav file from an array of samples, as long as you can describe the format.

Comment: @TimRoberts, the audio is generated from TTS model that I trained using tacotron2, in the example above I used waveglow as vocoder to generate an audio in wav format using the IPython display which only works in notebooks.

Comment: That doesn't really answer the question.  What IS `audio`?  What kind of object?  Repeating, if it is just an array of samples, the `wave` module can solve this.